# MongoDB searching for gaps in indices

Tags: mongodb

I am caching data from an online resource for future use in machine learning. This data is canonical and has no missing entries.

In the event that the real-time connection is dropped or the machine rebooted, I have a safeguard in place that does a historical search for a range of ids that are missing from the cache.

What I have yet to implement, however, is a mechanism for searching through the collection and identifying ranges where id values have been skipped.

For instance:

```
{"entry_id": 27497713, ...}
{"entry_id": 27497761, ...}
```

This data has a clear gap where entries are missing between `27497713` and `27497761`.

Is there a way I can find such a gap using queries? Perhaps at least narrowing it down by selecting values between two ranges and checking the count of returned entries? Given how many entries the collection contains, I am trying to avoid lots of queries for efficiency.

Comment: What about double counting? Do you have a unique index on the `entry_id` field to prevent the same id to be recorded twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

can you try this aggregation

1. `$group` - get `$min` and `$max`
2. `$addFields` - generate `$range` by `$min` and `$max` `entry_id`
3. `$lookup` - self lookup with generated range ids and entry ids
4. `$project` - get only non matching range ids using `setDifference`

pipeline

```
db.entries.aggregate(
    [
        {$group : {_id : null, min : {$min : "$entry_id"}, max : {$max : "$entry_id"}}},
        {$addFields : {rangeIds : {$range : ["$min", "$max"]}}},
        {$lookup : {from : "entries", localField : "rangeIds", foreignField : "entry_id", as : "entries"}},
        {$project : {_id :0, missingIds : {$setDifference : ["$rangeIds", "$entries.entry_id"]}}}
    ]
)
```

collection

```
> db.entries.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6fea9b7346ce591a17ad22"), "entry_id" : 27497713 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6fea9b7346ce591a17ad23"), "entry_id" : 27497761 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6fea9b7346ce591a17ad24"), "entry_id" : 27497750 }
>
```

aggregate result

```
> db.entries.aggregate( [ {$group : {_id : null, min : {$min : "$entry_id"}, max : {$max : "$entry_id"}}}, {$addFields : {rangeIds : {$range : ["$min", "$max"]}}}, {$lookup : {from : "entries", localField : "rangeIds", foreignField : "entry_id", as : "entries"}}, {$project : {_id :0, missingIds : {$setDifference : ["$rangeIds", "$entries.entry_id"]}}} ] )
{ "missingIds" : [ 27497714, 27497715, 27497716, 27497717, 27497718, 27497719, 27497720, 27497721, 27497722, 27497723, 27497724, 27497725, 27497726, 27497727, 27497728, 27497729, 27497730, 27497731, 27497732, 27497733, 27497734, 27497735, 27497736, 27497737, 27497738, 27497739, 27497740, 27497741, 27497742, 27497743, 27497744, 27497745, 27497746, 27497747, 27497748, 27497749, 27497751, 27497752, 27497753, 27497754, 27497755, 27497756, 27497757, 27497758, 27497759, 27497760 ] }
>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It does indeed do what I would like it to do. There is a problem however. I am using NodeJS with the official MongoDB driver, and from what I understand this is loading the entire dataset to check for gaps. The driver has a 64mb memory limit that is hit with this solution, as my collection contains 37 million entries. Is it shipping the entire collection to the client and aggregating there? And if so, can I specify it to aggregate on MongoDB's side instead?

Comment: you may need to use aggregate option `allowDiskUse:true` to use the disk space, otherwise we can specify range with some min, max limit

Comment: @Saravana Can you help me to solve this question? It is very similar to this one but little different. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61921598/how-to-get-set-of-missing-consecutive-numbers-array-only-has-low-and-high-mongod